# Add Android View edge to edge on target image using opengl

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, vuforia, image-recognition

I need to display an android view over target image using openGL, right now I'm recognizing and augmenting image with video using vuforia on android, but I need to display an android view such as viewpager over target image, how can I do that

Thanks